# java - check for same values in list

Tags: java, list

I have a list with an amount of "turtles" created. This is just some of the code, not all.

```
int nrTurtles = Keyboard.nextInt("How many turtles to create: ");
w = new GraphicsWindow(500, 300);
for (int k = 1; k <= nrTurtles; k++) {
        Turtle t = new Turtle(w, 50, 50 + 10*k);
            turtles.add(t);
}
```

And each turtle has a coordination value that i can get with (example):

```
turtles.get(0).getX() //this gets turtle nr 1 position
```

Now how do i on a smart way **check if two or more turtles** depending on how many there are in the list **has the same coordination value** ( **a fix value of 450**)?

**And** if two or more has the same value (450) i want to write with **system.out.print** that "turtle1 and turtle2 are the ones", if it happens that turtle1 and turtle2 has the same value.

**If there is only one turtle** having the value of (450) and **no other**, i want to write only that turtle, for ex. "turtle1 is the only one".

Comment: Does your `Turtle` class have the `equals()` method implemented?

Comment: Can you subclass them/edit the code and add a equals method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is just to iterate through the list and compare the relevant values, if they match then add the matching turtles to a results list.

Unless the list of turtles is sorted you're pretty much restricted to iteration as a technique for searching the list.

2nd EDIT:

```
ArrayList<Turtle> results = new ArrayList<Turtle>();

for (int i = 0; i < nrTurtles; i++) {

    if (turtles.get(i).getX() == 450) {

        results.add(turtles.get(i));
    }
}

if (results.size() == 0) {

    // No turtles are at 450

} else if (results.size() == 1) {

    // Turtle is alone at 450

} else {

    // Turtles are all at 450
}
```

Comment: Yes, that looks good, but just one question. What if the position of the two turtles are 300, then your code would check if turtles with 300 are equal. I wanted only to test if the value was 450. Hope u understand what i mean.

Comment: Is this O(n^2)? Also, this doesn't really work for 3 and more turtles "together".

Comment: I've edited the answer to show what I think you're looking for. If this is homework though you should really take a good crack at it yourself first. @Piskvor yes, it was O(n^2). I agree that Hashtables are very useful but it didn't seem like that was the sort of thing he was after.

Comment: Ahh, that is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you so much! Yes this was a homework and i will definitly look at your example and learn. When i code i don't like to copy and paste, i want to understand ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a structure like this (pseudocode):

```
HashTable{
  450 => Array{ 1, 5 },
  300 => Array{ 2 },
  150 => Array{ 3, 4, 6 } 
}
```

where the key is coordination value, and the value is an array of turtles that have it.

Filling the structure:

```
for each turtle:
  get coord value
  do we have it as a key yet?
    no: create coord.value => empty array
  insert turtle id into coord.value array
```

Printing it out is just a matter of iterating over it.

Comment: (if you only need turtles with coord.value 450, just add a check "get coord value, if not 450, continue")

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map<Integer, Set<Turtle>>`:

- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

with the key being the X coordinate. Take a look here for how to use HashMaps:

- http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/how-to-use-of-hashmap.html

Basically, loop through all the turtles and add it to your map. Something like:

```
Map<Integer, Set<Turtle>> map = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Turtle>>();
for(Turtle t: turtles) {
   Set<Turtle> set = m.get(t.getX());
   if(set == null) {
      s = new HashSet<Turtle>();
      map.put(t.getX(), set);
   }
   map.put(t.getX(), set);
}
```

Then you just go through the elements and see if there are more then one:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Turtle>> e: map.entrySet()) {
   Set<Turtle> set = e.getValue();
   if(set.size() > 1) {
       System.out.println("These turtles have the same X coordinate:");
       for(Turtle t: set) {
          System.out.println(t);
       }
   }
}
```